# SQL crosstab query phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables.

nsolistings contains:

```
code | description | status
1    | test        | unselected
```

The 2nd is areas2013, in which the code from column eacode corresponds to nsolistings.code:

```
eacode | team | subteam | teamleader
1      | 2    | 3       | Susan
```

I need an sql code will get all the unselected and match with the table.

Comment: what have you tried so far, which is the specific part you are having a problem with? do you want to do a join on the two tables?

Comment: yes I want to join the 2 tables. I do it in MSACESS but i want to do it on mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

```
SELECT * FROM nsolistings INNER JOIN areas2013 ON areas2013.eacode=nsolistings.code AND nsolistings.status="selected";
```

This will join the two tables returning all columns and select the rows in which status is "selected". Sample:

```
   1 | test | selected | 1 | 2| 3| Susan
```